# ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am attempting to run below code.

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
```

And I am receiving below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-ebfa5cfc2bb8> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics' (C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 13):

`plot_confusion_matrix` **deprecated** now so use [`sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn-metrics-confusionmatrixdisplay)

[image]

---

**PIP**

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
or 
conda update -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error i.e. cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' when running my notebook via Kaggle kernel. Even tried to upgrade sklearn via this command -> !pip install --upgrade scikit-learn. But still I'm getting the above error.

Comment: @SanushiSalgado did you solve the issue ?

Comment: I have that with version 1.2.1

Comment: @Soren Use `sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay`. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay` instead?

Document Here: [sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix**

**from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay**

Use these two for instead

```
  for cls in classifiers:
  
    cls.fit(x_train,np.argmax(y_train,axis=1))

    colors = [ 'YlOrBr', 'GnBu', 'Pastel2', 'PuRd']
    for cls, ax, c in zip(classifiers, axes.flatten(), colors):
    cm = confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y_test, axis=1), cls.predict(x_test))
    disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, 
    display_labels=names1)
    disp.plot(ax=ax, cmap=c)
    ax.title.set_text(type(cls).__name__)
 plt.tight_layout()  
 plt.show()
```