# cannot import plot_confusion_matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am not able to import the `plot_confusion_matrix` attribute from `sklearn.metrics` module.

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ebfa5cfc2bb8> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_confusion_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics' (/Users/sudhanmagic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'plot\_confusion\_matrix' from 'sklearn.metrics'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967530/importerror-cannot-import-name-plot-confusion-matrix-from-sklearn-metrics)

Answer (score 4):

`plot_confusion_matrix` was added in [`v0.22`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.22.html#id8), if you're seeing this error it most likely means you have an old version of `scikit-learn` installed.

Upgrading should fix this:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```